# Image displaying won't work when depending on a variable name

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm developing a small game in Java, and i need to show an image. This image is located in a sprite folder on my disk. Basically, i have this structure :

```
public class mainClass extends JFrame {
   private int imageType; // The type of the image
   public mainClass() {
       windowContent = new WindowContent(gameBoard, nextPiece);
       this.setContentPane(windowContent);
       while(!gameOver) { 
           this.imageType = otherClass.getImageType(); // Short version
           this.repaint();
       }
   }

   class WindowContent extends JPanel {
       private int imageType;
       public WindowContent(int imgType) {
          this.imageType = imgType;
       }
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
           try {
               BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read("srprites/" + this.imageType + ".png");
               g.drawImage(img, 200,200, null);
           } catch ....... 
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is that the first image shows up normally, but when the variable content change nothing happend. The first image just stays the same. I tried a lot of things like moving the `this.setContentPane()`, but nothing worked. Is there a way to make this work correctly ?
Thanks.

Comment: ```int``` is a primitive type so by changing value of ```imageType``` in the main class, you won't change the ```imageType``` in the ```WindowContent```. You need to set imageType directly on WindowContent.

Comment: Does the code throw any Exceptions?  I notice you're reading from the "srprites" folder, did you mean to type "sprites", or are you getting any FileNotFoundExceptions?

Comment: Yes it's sprites, typo from me. Concerning exception, it's all handled in full program, i just wanted to be short here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imageType` in your WindowContent is only assigned in a constructor. By changing the value of `imageType` in the main class, you won't change the `imageType` in the WindowContent. You need to set `imageType` directly on WindowContent.

Instead of

```
  while(!gameOver) { 
       this.imageType = otherClass.getImageType(); // Short version
       this.repaint();
  }
```

you need to do

```
  while(!gameOver) { 
       windowContent.setImageType(otherClass.getImageType()); // Short version
       this.repaint();
  }
```

And of course add the setter to windowContent

Comment: I'm having quite a strange problem doing this. I add a standard setter method `public void setImageType(int newType) ...` and i can't compile : error : can't resolve method setImageType(int). Is there an encapsulation or publicity problem here ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. I see you accepted the answer. Did you find what's wrong?

Comment: Yes, i forget to add the solution : i was casting my windowContent object with `JPanel windowContent = new....` instate of `WindowContent windowContent = new...`. Works fine now. Thanks.